# Algebra Involving Factorials and Complex Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, factorial

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Why is the following true? $$\frac{(iz)^{2n}}{(2n)!} + \frac{(iz)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{(iz)^{n}}{n!}$$
I’m following a [proof of Euler’s formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula#Proof) and comprehend everything but this last step. The furthest I’ve gotten is: $$\frac{(iz)^{2n}}{(2n)!} + \frac{(iz)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{(iz)^{2n}((2n + 1) + (iz))}{(2n+1)(2n)!}$$
What am I missing?

Comment: Who says that that equality holds?

Comment: I got it from the [proofwiki.org](https://proofwiki.org/) proof I linked [in the question.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula#Proof) It’s possible that either the proof is incorrect or that I’m misreading it.

Comment: It is fine, but you are misreading it. See the answer that you got.

Comment: You are correct, I made the equality wrong by omitting the infinite sums.

Comment: This is called an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @joriki Interesting, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That equality is false. However, what is written at that link is not that. It's$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(iz)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{(iz)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(iz)^n}{n!},\label{a}\tag1$$which is indeed true, since both series are equal to$$\frac1{0!}+\frac{iz}{1!}+\frac{(iz)^2}{2!}+\frac{(iz)^3}{3!}+\cdots$$More precisely, the LHS of \eqref{a} is what you get when you group in pairs the RHS of \eqref{a}, which is a legitimate choice, since we are dealing with absolutely convergent series here.

Comment: I see — thank you for the help!